# phpmailer wont send email after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

Im messing around with phpmailer and i've got everything working. 
But what im trying to do now is after submitting a form send a mail.
Not anything too difficult just a basic email that acknowledges the form has been submitted (no form data).

problem : email is not sending after submitting form (email code is working 100% tested)

Hope someone can help me out :)

mail.php code :

```
<?php
//ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);

include '/var/www/includes/mailer.php';

//require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;

 $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                 // Enable verbose      debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to  use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.nicetrygoyim.nl';                       //Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication


$mail->Username = 'secret@secret.com';          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'nicetry';                             // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('secret@secret.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('secret@secret.com', 'secret');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('secret@secret.com', 'secret');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('secret@secret.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

  $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
  $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';


   $mail->smtpConnect([
   'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
     ]
      ]);

     if(!$mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
    ?>
```

my Form :

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
 Leerlingnummer:<br>
 <input type="text" name="leerlingnummer"required placeholder="Voer hier het leerlingnummer in" /><br>
 E-mailadres:<br>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="groottext" value="Reparatie    indienen"/>
```

edit : typo 
edit : forgot to mention problem

Comment: Which server you use?

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya i use my own server (debian 8)

Comment: and what is the issue?? What is not working?

Comment: @LelioFaieta oh frig i forgot to mention.

Comment: @LelioFaieta i've edited it so it mentions my problem :)

Comment: and what kind of error do you get? Enable error reporting while developing and see what is the error.

Comment: @LelioFaieta i've got error reporting on but it doesn't show anything because the script is working (when i test it in ssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is running, you should be seeing a ton of debug output, even if it is working correctly. You don't actually say what the problem is, but you're doing a few things wrong that I can see. It would really help if you based your code on the examples provided and read [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) instead of just guessing.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
```

should be:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Don't call `smtpConnect()` yourself, you'll mess up the tracking of SMTP transaction state. If you want to set SSL params, set them the expected way and then just call `send()`, which will deal with the connection:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

The next question is why are you doing that? If you can't provide an explicit, specific reason for doing that, you're doing something wrong.